# ASCII CMD коды в PHP

Tags: php, md5, ascii

Есть строка, которая хешируется **md5()** 
`md5($salt + /* ASCII код */ + $second_salt);` 
Как я понял с помощью **ASCII** кода `0x7F` (CMD — DEL) мы можем удалить `$salt`, но как это реализовать я не понимаю, что мы должны вставить, чтобы у нас удалился `$salt`

Comment: Ой, скорее всего не DEL, а BS `0x08`

Comment: Вы можете редактировать свой вопрос)

Comment: @Suvitruf я просто не уверен до сих пор, как именно это сработает)

Comment: В php строки конкатенируются оператором "точка", а не `+`, так что ваше выражение в любом случае возьмет md5(0) и управляющие ascii коды внутри строк не действуют. они управляющие только для терминала.

Comment: @mike, я знаю, имелось ввиду как получается строка для хеширования

Comment: Т.е. ascii код у вас не в переменной, а непосредственно в коде и стирает опять же не содержимое переменной, а часть самого кода ?